# ROW_NUM function causing ORA-00913: too many values Error? Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, row-number

All,

I am trying to pair two or more records in a grandparent table so that I can then find its grand children records using one grandchild to start from.

So the structure is like so

- S_ASSET  **x 1 record**
- S_ASSET_X **x 2 child records**
- CX_ASSET_XM x **1 grand child records**

Therefore the cardinality is one Grandparent can have 2 Grandchild records

This CX_ASSET_XM table will hold information about TCP/IP calls of a Grandchild asset. These calls are not synchronized. therefore one Grandchild asset may make a call today but the other one has not made a call since yesterday.

In my query I find all the grand children records that have been created today (sysdate) and then traverse up the relationship to find the Grandparent, then I traverse back down to find the other twin in the Grandchildren tuple.

The problem with my query is that it returns every single TCP/IP call a pair has made but I only want the most recent callback of each grandchild to analyse

Here is an illustration

[image]

So to minimize my result set I am trying to use a ROW_NUM function to get only the results I need which is the most recent callback date for each grand child record.

**Query**

```
SELECT cb.ssid, cb.created_by, cb.callback_date, cb.callback_num,
       asset.desc_text, asset.prom_integ_id, asset.integration_id
       --Traversing Up to find the Grandparent record of
FROM   SIEBEL.CX_ASSET_XM cb
       JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET_X assetx ON cb.SSID = assetx.attrib_37
       JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET asset ON assetx.par_row_id = asset.row_id
WHERE  asset.prom_integ_id IN
--Traversing Down to find the other pair
(   SELECT asset.prom_integ_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cb.ssid
                                  ORDER BY cb.callback_date DESC)
    FROM   SIEBEL.CX_ASSET_XM cb
           JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET_X assetx ON cb.ssid = assetx.attrib_37
           JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET asset ON assetx.par_row_id = asset.row_id
);
```

**Error**

```
ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 36
```

Am I using the ROW_NUM and PARTITION correctly in this query structure?

Thanks

ORACLE DB Version is **10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit**

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you need to accomplish, could you provide a sample data with all the ids of the records etc. and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use IN operator which, in this case, expects one set of values to work on, but the subquery returns two columns, not one:

```
WHERE asset.prom_integ_id IN
--Traversing Down to find the other pair
(   SELECT asset.prom_integ_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cb.ssid ORDER BY cb.callback_date DESC)
```

Should be:

```
WHERE asset.prom_integ_id IN
--Traversing Down to find the other pair
(   SELECT asset.prom_integ_id
```

And, starting with that, I guess that the value returned from ROW_NUMBER should be accessed earlier, so it would look like this:

```
SELECT cb.ssid, cb.created_by, cb.callback_date, cb.callback_num, asset.desc_text, asset.prom_integ_id, asset.integration_id
--Traversing Up to find the Grandparent record of
FROM SIEBEL.CX_ASSET_XM cb
    JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET_X assetx
      ON cb.SSID = assetx.attrib_37
    JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET asset
      ON assetx.par_row_id = asset.row_id
WHERE asset.prom_integ_id IN
--Traversing Down to find the other pair
(   SELECT prom_integ_id
    FROM (
SELECT asset.prom_integ_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cb.ssid ORDER BY cb.callback_date DESC) row_n
    FROM SIEBEL.CX_ASSET_XM cb
    JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET_X assetx
      ON cb.ssid = assetx.attrib_37
    JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET asset
      ON assetx.par_row_id = asset.row_id
) where row_n = 1
);
```

I'm not sure it is what you wanted - can you check it?

Comment: This works but I am still getting older grand children records as well as the most recent one. How can I filter this out?

Comment: The only other option is I filter it out in my Java application but I guess this is not solving the query problem.

Comment: Give me few minutes, I have to create a test case. Can you please provide sample data?